# Networked Flextesa possible?

Tags: sandbox, network, private

I am trying to run a private test-network over multiple VMs.
The Flextesa approach seems very easy to deploy but only allows for local sandboxes. Has anybody ever tried to connect multiple [Flextesa](https://gitlab.com/tezos/flextesa) sandboxes over a network or is it hard-coded to not allow such approaches? The [K8s](https://github.com/oxheadalpha/tezos-k8s) approach is not usable for me because of Kubernetes.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Flextesa's `mini-net` has an option `--add-external-peer-port` to allow other nodes.

It has been used to test 1 node joining the sandbox (incl. as a baker → in order to test Kiln).

I don't know of any attempt to make larger networks but it's worth a try.